# Angular Routing - Redirect on Empty No `pathMatch`

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I am following the Angular Tour of Heroes Guide. I have stumbled upon the "[default route](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt5#add-a-default-route)" section and decided to try getting rid of the `pathMatch` attribute of the Route corresponding to the empty string.

Here is how my code looks:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'hero-details', component: HeroDetailComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard'}
]
```

The behavior I encounter is a blank page whatever the address is.

If I change the last path, I experience something differently.

```js
{path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

Now, even if I target a nonexisting route, I get redirected to the default path (and not redirected), and the `index.html` is shown.

**What's strange for me here is why the former one does not behave similarly. Why does it not redirect me to the `index.html`?**

Changing the last path to use `pathMatch: 'prefix'` behaves even more unexpectedly.

```js
{path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'prefix'}
```

**Similarly, if I target a nonexisting address, I get redirected to the `index.html`, even though everywhere is said that `''` prefixes everything, so shouldn't I be redirected to `'dashboard'`?**

I would be extremely grateful if someone clears this concept up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all in the docs you will find all about `pathMatch`. Look [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Route).

> The path-matching strategy, one of 'prefix' or 'full'. Default is 'prefix'.

> By default, the router checks URL elements from the left to see if the URL matches a given path and stops when there is a config match. Importantly there must still be a config match for each segment of the URL. For example, '/team/11/user' matches the prefix 'team/:id' if one of the route's children matches the segment 'user'. That is, the URL '/team/11/user' matches the config {path: 'team/:id', children: [{path: ':user', component: User}]} but does not match when there are no children as in {path: 'team/:id', component: Team}.

> The path-match strategy 'full' matches against the entire URL. It is important to do this when redirecting empty-path routes. Otherwise, because an empty path is a prefix of any URL, the router would apply the redirect even when navigating to the redirect destination, creating an endless loop.

**How will it works now?**

If you enter a url which "not" exists, so you need todo a special thing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'hero-details', component: HeroDetailComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard'}
]
```

The `path: '**'` will catch all undefined routes and redirect now to your dashboard. So the blank page you told will not longer display.

The full path mean: *Only if the route **IS** the path -> true*
The prefix (which still is the **default** by Angular): *Contains the url the path -> true.*

Why we need the **full** path match in `path: ''`? The "empty" path so to say is in every url. So it can be always true if no other match found.

Comment: Damn, I hadn't known that the default value is `prefix`... However, it turns out that Angular throws `Error: NG04014` if no explicit `pathMatch` is defined on the empty path, as "The default value of 'pathMatch' is 'prefix', but often the intent is to use 'full'." 

Still, I cannot understand why putting `pathMatch: 'prefix'` on the empty path does not redirect everything to the 'dashboard' page. When I try to reach a random address (i.e. 'a'), the thrown error is `Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes.`.

Comment: Which Angular version are you using? And: it only make sense to use "full" in a empty route. All other will be always true

Comment: Angular 14. I agree it makes sense to use it only with 'ful', but I decided to play around and see what the behavior would be and realized when 'prefix', it does not actually match everything, but rather throws the beforehand mentioned error.

Comment: I have googled a little and: Yes, since Version 14 angular must have the `full` path on empty routes. < 14 you could use both. If my post helps you, you can set it as answer. Thx!

Comment: Would you share the resource? I seem unable to find such a thing and everyone says “” prefixes anything.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73208616/upgrade-from-angular-13-to-14-routing-problem-error-ng04014
Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75171393/angular-14-ng04014-invalid-configuration-of-route

Comment: This is actually wrong. I ended up downgrading my angular version and encountered the exact same behaviour. It seems as '' (together with the 'prefix') matches _none_ but the empty route itself, whereas the __wildcard__ matches everything.

Comment: But again, this makes absolutely sense. I have never used prefix with empty routes.